# Display uploaded image from my extension

Tags: magento-1.9

I did upload of image according to https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/How+to+create+an+image+or+video+uploader+for+the+Magento+Admin+Panel everything works just do not know how to display in frontend and backend

Comment: where you want to show in admin panel? edit form

Comment: under uploader images
http://pastebin.com/RrXv6e7w

Comment: insert after `(media)` your directory with the image in the database it will show automatically..

Answer (score 1):

```
 <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') ?>yourimagedirectory/images/<?php echo $yourimagehere;?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: but If I want display all images from directory ?

Comment: you add your loop on that to display single image at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `system.xml`:

```
...
<artur_image_field translate="label comment">
    <label>Artur's Image Field</label>
    <comment>Allowed file types: ICO, PNG, GIF, JPG, JPEG, APNG, SVG. Not all browsers support all these formats!</comment>
    <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
    <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">uploaddir</upload_dir>
    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">uploaddir</base_url>
    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</artur_image_field>    
...
```

Then you can call it with the following:

```
public function getArtursImage() {

    $folderName = 'uploaddir';
    $storeConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('magentos_sekcja/magentos_grupa/artur_image_field');
    $arturImageFile = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $folderName . '/' . $storeConfig;
    $absolutePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/' . $folderName . '/' . $storeConfig;

    if(!is_null($storeConfig) && $this->_isFile($absolutePath)) {
        $url = $arturImageFile;
    } else {
        $url = ''; //Placeholder here
    }
    return $url;

}
```

PS: Run the above in a `PHP Block` file, not directly in your template

Comment: This is uploader my is work I need display all images from directory media/uploaddir/default 
I think it's going to be using foreach